# Possible Bug while Updating User Profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, email

**Steps to Repeat**
1) Login to stackoverflow.com

2) Click "Edit Profile and Settings"

[image: Edit Profile]

3) Click save
[image]

Comment: Did you change your email?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Profile email addresses aren't verified by default; you can put *anything* in that field, as long as it hasn't been used by another user.

...This means that occasionally someone will get lazy, and just enter "me@stackoverflow.com" or whatever pops into their head.

...Which is a problem when we hire someone who happens to have that name and he tries to use his *real* company email address in his profile. BTW, you should mention that you're an employee in your profile when you go to edit it, **which you should be able to do now** since I took the fake email address off that *other* Dan's profile.

For anyone else encountering this, don't hesitate to contact our support team using the link in the footer of every page on the site - we'll get it sorted out.

Comment: Employees don't get the ♦ by default?

Comment: @apaul34208 Apparently *Nope* http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161197 :-|

Comment: Thanks Shog, I was actually going to do that very thing when I hit this problem :)